# How to create a countdown timer that triggers an event on ending?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I found one article to set up a simple timer and that works fine. But Im trying to get something to execute when it gets to 0. Here is what I have so far:

I run this one time to create the timer variable:

```
scoreboard objectives add timerObjective dummy "Timer Objective"
scoreboard players set nonexistenuser timerObjective 100
scoreboard objectives setdisplay sidebar timerObjective
```

I then create a command block that runs every 20 ticks (1 second) to decrement the timer:

```
scoreboard players remove @a timerObjective 1
execute @a[name=nonexistenuser,scores={timerObjective=0}] ~ ~ ~ fill 1049 1 1050 1001 49 1049 air
```

This does count down from 100 and I can see it in the display it shows the score for user `nonexistentuser`. But when it hits 0 it does not execute the command because there is no actual player called `nonexistentuser`. If I replace name with my own ID it works because I am an actual player. I tested the command manually and found the selector `@a[name=nonexistenuser,scores={timerObjective=0}]` returns no targets even though I can see the score for this "player" in the display. So is there some other way I can create a simple countdown timer that does something at the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can instead use `/scoreboard players test`:

```
/scoreboard players test nonexistentuser timerObjective 0 0
```

The command succeeds if the number is 0, and fails if it is not. Just place a conditional chain command block after that with your `/fill` command and it will only execute if the command succeeds.

Comment: Yes that works thanks! I typically prefer to work with function files and a single command block because command blocks are annoying to set up. It would be great if there was a way to set up a command block completely via a function (haven't found a way to set the command blocks command without manually typing it in). I'm trying to find the best way to create multiple timers without having to do a bunch of setup for each.

Answer (score 0):

I found one option that I can live with for multiple timers and I can extend it to as many times as I want. It uses several function files but each timer can be tracked and works independently from the other timers. Solution requires just one repeating command block. You can start the timer via a second command block (/function timer1Start for example), call the timer1start function directly in console, or call timer1Start from some other function.

I am creating a build battle feature so there will just be some button the user clicks that will execute another function buildBattle. The buildBattle function in turn will directly call /function timer1Start. With 3 timers I can have 3 different build battles at the same time each on their own timer and each can execute a separate function when complete.

I guess the same could be set up without functions using a bunch of command blocks - but who wants to do that ;)

I created these files:

global:

- timerInit.mcfunction: execute this one time to set up all timers
- TimerTick.mcfunction: put this in a repeating command block that runs every 20 ticks

timer1 files

- timer1start.mcfunction:

  - sets active timer to 1 and starts a 15 second timer
  - call /function timer1start to start the timer
- timer1tick.mcfunction: anything in here will execute once per second
- timer1done.mcfunction: anything in here will execute once after timer1 expires

timer2 files

- timer2start.mcfunction:

  - sets active timer to 2 and starts a 30 second timer
  - call /function timer2start to start the timer
- timer2tick.mcfunction: anything in here will execute once per second
- timer2done.mcfunction: anything in here will execute once after timer2 expires

timer3 files

- timer3start.mcfunction: sets active timer to 3 and starts a 45 second timer

  - sets active timer to 3 and starts a 45 second timer
  - call /function timer3start to start this timer
- timer3tick.mcfunction: anything in here will execute once per second
- timer3done.mcfunction: anything in here will execute once after timer3 expires

timerInit.mcfunction:

```
scoreboard objectives add timer1 dummy "Timer 1"
scoreboard objectives add timer2 dummy "Timer 2"
scoreboard objectives add timer3 dummy "Timer 3"
scoreboard objectives add activeTimer dummy "activeTimer"
```

TimerTick.mcfunction:

```
#update the 3 individual timers
scoreboard players remove timeTracker1 timer1 1
scoreboard players remove timeTracker2 timer2 1
scoreboard players remove timeTracker3 timer3 1

#synch each players timer with the time tracker 'player' 
scoreboard players operation @a timer1 = timeTracker1 timer1
scoreboard players operation @a timer2 = timeTracker2 timer2
scoreboard players operation @a timer3 = timeTracker3 timer3

#update all players to show them their active timer in the side bar (optional)
execute @a[scores={activeTimer=1}] ~ ~ ~ scoreboard objectives setdisplay sidebar timer1
execute @a[scores={activeTimer=2}] ~ ~ ~ scoreboard objectives setdisplay sidebar timer2
execute @a[scores={activeTimer=3}] ~ ~ ~ scoreboard objectives setdisplay sidebar timer3

#execute something every second for the timers (for instance show time or some other command)
function timer1Tick
function timer2Tick
function timer3Tick

#execute these functions ONE TIME when the timer expires
execute @p[scores={timer1=-1}] ~ ~ ~ function timer1Done
execute @p[scores={timer2=-1}] ~ ~ ~ function timer2Done
execute @p[scores={timer3=-1}] ~ ~ ~ function timer3Done
```

timer1start.mcfunction

```
scoreboard players set @a timer1 15
scoreboard players set timeTracker1 timer1 15
scoreboard players set @a activeTimer 1
```

timer1tick.mcfunction:

```
#execute @a[scores={activeTimer=1}] ~ ~ ~ say hello
title @a[scores={timer1=10,activeTimer=1}] actionbar 10 seconds left
title @a[scores={timer1=9,activeTimer=1}] actionbar 9
title @a[scores={timer1=8,activeTimer=1}] actionbar 8
title @a[scores={timer1=7,activeTimer=1}] actionbar 7
title @a[scores={timer1=6,activeTimer=1}] actionbar 6
title @a[scores={timer1=5,activeTimer=1}] actionbar 5
title @a[scores={timer1=4,activeTimer=1}] actionbar 4
title @a[scores={timer1=3,activeTimer=1}] actionbar 3
title @a[scores={timer1=2,activeTimer=1}] actionbar 2
title @a[scores={timer1=1,activeTimer=1}] actionbar 1
title @a[scores={timer1=0,activeTimer=1}] actionbar  Times up!
```

timer1Done.mcfunction

```
#do something when the timer completes
title @a[scores={timer1=..0}] actionbar timer 1 countdown complete
```

timer2start.mcfunction

```
scoreboard players set @a timer2 30
scoreboard players set timeTracker2 timer2 30
scoreboard players set @a activeTimer 2
```

timer2tick.mcfunction:

```
#do something when timer 2 executes
```

timer2Done.mcfunction:

```
#do something when timer 2 expires
```

timer3start.mcfunction

```
scoreboard players set @a timer3 45
scoreboard players set timeTracker3 timer3 45
scoreboard players set @a activeTimer 3
```

timer3tick.mcfunction:

```
#do something when timer 3 executes
```

timer3Done.mcfunction:

```
#do something when timer 3 expires
```

Comment: One other note that caused me some frustration. In bedrock you need to put the repeating command block in a location that is loaded or the timer stops when you get too far away. You can do it in Bedrock with the tickingarea command and in java edition placing the block in the worldspawn.

Comment: You can also just put it at world spawn, just like java